# getting individual elements of a cached jquery object

Tags: jquery, html-select

```
var obj = $("form select");
alert(obj.find(":selected:eq(0)").val()); // works
alert(obj.find(":selected:eq(1)").val()); // Does Not Work
```

How would I find the selected option from the rest of select elements using my cached obj?

```
var n = 2;
var nthSelected = $(":selected",obj[n]); //Seems to work
```

Accessing the individual elements of your cached objects can also be done with .filter() as follows:

```
alert(obj.filter(":eq(1)").val());
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to loop through all ':selected' options, I'm wondering about accessing the (nth > 0) elements of my cached object. I'm hoping to avoid a loop actually, because it's probably just as fast to select the element directly without using my cached object (ex: $("form select:eq(1) :selected")) However, that is not what I'm asking about here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedValues = [];

obj.each(function() {
  var selected = $(':selected', this).val();
  selectedValues.push(selected);
});

//now you have an array of all the selected values.  :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var selects = $('form select');
var selected = $(':selected', selects);
```